# scroll view shows the button part of the page first

Tags: android, scrollview

I created an activity using scroll layout.
When the activity start, I see the buttom part of the page, so I need to scroll up to see top.
Someone know how to solve the problem? (to see the top part of the page first when the activity start?)
I tried to search the web about the scroll view, but didn't find any details about this specific problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just solve the problem, solved it by adding:
android:focusable="false"
to my EditText element in my XML.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ScrollView is the root of your view, that may happen because some view inside the ScrollView is gaining the focus.

Try to add this attribute `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to another view located at the top of the ScrollView and tell if it worked ;)!

Comment: I already solved the problem like I said at the comment above, but your solution is working too! thanks!
I would have voted you, but I have no 15 reputations yet.. :(